# How to verify if remote computer is available?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a part of a program that shall copy a batch of files from the current computer to a defined list of computers.
If these computers are not available, the code will hang for a long time trying to access them. Is there any functionallity in C# to check if the machine is available and then skip if it's not?

```
MFWs = File.ReadAllLines(GuiManager.MyConfigManagerConfig.MachinesList);
        foreach (string MFW in MFWs)
        {
          if (MFW != System.Environment.MachineName)
          {
            String target = @"\\" + MFW + @"\D\IbSi\config\" + Path.GetFileName(ConfigFile);
            String backup = @"\\" + MFW + @"\D\IbSi\userdata\" + Path.GetFileName(ConfigFile);
            try
            {
              File.Copy(source, target, true);
              File.Copy(source, backup, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              Manager.SendMessage("Failed to copy " + Path.GetFileName(ConfigFile) + " to " + MFW + "\n" + ex.Message);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: You're always dealing with "it could be available when you make the request to see if it's available, but not when you actually need it."; so your best bet is to try the operation.  There are certain things you can do; make sure the DNS entries are up to date on the local computer; maybe that will reduce the time resolution takes. Looks like this Stack Overflow question deals with just that; by using threads (or a Task) to do certain tasks (like file copy) and timing out if it takes too long: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232953/speed-up-file-exists-for-non-existing-network-shares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ping the computer before starting the copy (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804416/932282) answer):

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public static bool IsHostAvailable(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return pingable;
}
```

As noted in the comments you need to make sure the firewall on the servers is open for pings (ICMP echo requests)

Comment: Note, if the remote computer has been configured to block pings, then this routine will always return false even when the computer is available.