# Folder not avalible

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working from home with an Access project. I have a VPN connection to a customer that times out after 15 minutes if I don't use it. If the VPN is up my code below works fine. If the VPN is down the code gets stuck for 60 seconds, checking for a folder that is not available. Is there a way to change this to say 5 seconds and "do something else".

```
Sub check()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    If fso.FolderExists("z:\abc") Then
        'do something
    else
        'do something else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like that is not possible.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1667745/5162073).

Comment: Thank you for the link. It suggested pinging the server which is fast enough.

Comment: @BrianMStafford It's not possible to make it faster. It is possible to execute the command under a surrogate process, and move on with the main process if the surrogate has not returned a value (in a multithreaded language, one would use a thread for this instead with way less overhead, but VBA unfortunately is single-threaded). Also listed in the bottom answer there.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* actually implement this without pinging the server by using a second process to test if the folder exists. This is relevant when the path may or may not refer to a network share, for example.

The code starts a PowerShell process to check if the file exists, then waits for a set amount of time for that PowerShell process to complete, and moves on otherwise.

An added advantage of this approach is that you can call `DoEvents` while waiting, which will prevent Access from locking up even when waiting for your set timeout.

The disadvantage is that this will cause a considerable overhead if the expected time it'll take to run is short.

```
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "Z:\abc"
Dim cmd As String
cmd = "powershell.exe -c Test-Path '" & Replace(strPath, "'", "''") & "'"
Dim shellobj As Object
Set shellobj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmdObject As Object
Set cmdObject = shellobj.Exec(cmd)
Dim startTime As Single
startTime = Timer()
Dim fileExists As Boolean
Dim timeoutReached As Boolean
Do While cmdObject.Status = 0
    If Timer() - startTime > 30 Then
        timeoutReached = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    DoEvents
Loop
If Not timeoutReached Then
    fileExists = Trim(cmdObject.StdOut.ReadAll) = "True" & vbCrLf
End If
```

Comment: _this will cause a considerable overhead if the expected time it'll take to run is short._ You could let a Static variable hold the time of the last call and skip the call if less than 15 minutes have passed.

Comment: If that's a major consideration, one could also open PowerShell without the `-c` command and keep it open, then send commands using `cmdObject.StdIn.Write`, that avoids the overhead from opening Powershell for every command (which avoids most of the overhead but still provides non-cached results). However, I'd want to encapsulate that into a self-healing predeclared object and that would considerably lengthen this answer.