# Fastest way to identify Network Path Exists

Tags: c#, vb.net, networking, path

In my application I need to search for a network path and do some processing based on the existence of the folder. Let us take an example, I have to search for a path on network and if path exists I have to enable some controls otherwise I need to disable the controls.
I tried using DirectoryInfo object and getting the correct values:

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\ServerIPAddress\FolderName");

    if(dirInfo.Exists)
    {
            //do something
    }
    else
    {
           //do something else
    }
```

The problem with the above code is it is consuming more than 2 minutes for getting the Exists property.

Is there any faster way to check for network path existence.

Thanks and regards,
Ashish Sharma

Comment: You mean `@"\\ServerIPAddress\FolderName"` (two backslash)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid network stalls in GetFileAttributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142080/how-to-avoid-network-stalls-in-getfileattributes)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726602/how-to-prevent-timeout-when-inspecting-unavailable-network-share-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this would take time only if the folder does not exist in the specified path.
You could use a different thread to check the existence of the folder as described here (along with delegates): [How to avoid network stalls in GetFileAttributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142080/how-to-avoid-network-stalls-in-getfileattributes)

Also you can check this related question: [How To: Prevent Timeout When Inspecting Unavailable Network Share - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726602/how-to-prevent-timeout-when-inspecting-unavailable-network-share-c-sharp)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Don't have that privilege yet :(

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I am right now using the approach specified by you. For the time being problem is resolved but I may require to find a new way soon!